# Fragments and ViewPager in Android

Tags: java, android, android-viewpager, fragment

I am having a ViewPager to allow the user to slide between 5 different views where each "view" extends Fragment.

I have my own adapter which extend FragmentPagerAdapter and which implement getItem() as

```
@Override public Fragment getItem(int position) {
   switch(position) {
      case 0: 
          return new TextDescriptionFragment();
      // Handle the 4 other cases the same way
   }
}
```

This works fine and the user can swipe between the 5 different views. But here comes the problem: Each of the first 4 views contains Views such as Button and  EditText which the user can interact with.

And I then want the last page(Page number 5) to show all the user input values from all the views from the 4 previous pages(fragments). How do I do that?

I can't find any way to read the user input values from the previous fragments. The views may not even exist anymore(But will be recreated if the user goes back).

And I can't seem to get the existing fragments.

Comment: But I can't get the fragments for the 4 first pages. They may not even exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would consider having a custom object that keeps the data each fragment fills. Something like:

```
public class FillerData implements Parcelable {
    private String page0$data0;
    private String page0$data1;
    private String page0$data2;

    // getters and setters if you wish

    // implement Parcelable interface as this object will be managed by host activity
}
```

You'll have only one such object managed by parent activity and the parent activity will implement an interface for exposing this object:

```
public static interface FillerDataExposer {
    public FillerData exposeFiller();
}

public class MyFragmentHostActivity extends FragmentActivity implements FillerDataExposer {
    private static final String FILLER_KEY = "FILLER_KEY";
    private FillerData myFillerData;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstance) {
        .......
        if(savedInstance != null) {
            myFillerData = (FillerData) savedInstance.getParcelable(FILLER_KEY);
        } else {
            myFillerData = new FillerData();
        }
    }

    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstance) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState();
        savedInstance.putExtra(FILLER_KEY, myFillerData);
    }

    public FillerData exposeFiller() {
        return this.myFillerData;
    }
}
```

Now, each of your fragments will have access to that centralized data filler object through parent activity. To reduce the weight of your code, all your fragments could extend from a base fragment class that provides access to `FillerDataExposer` implementation (actually, the parent activity):

```
public abstract class AbstractFillerFragment extends Fragment {
    protected FillerDataExposer dataExposer;

    public void onAttach(Activity act) {
        super.onAttach(act);
        // make sure no ClassCastExceptions
        this.dataExposer = (FillerDataExposer) act;
    }
}
```

Fragments that should only record the data filled could look like this:

```
public class Page1Fragment extends AbstractFillerFragment {

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = // inflate XML resource ...
        yourEditText = (EditText) view.findViewById(...);
        // other relevant code ....
    }

    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       yourEditText.setText(dataExposer.exposeFiller.setPageX$DataY());
       // some code for EditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() could look like:
        yourEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

          public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            dataExposer.exposeFiller().setPage1$Data0(s.toString());

          }

          public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {}

          public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {}
       });
    }
}
```

While the fragment that needs to have access to all data stored could look like this:

```
public class FinalFragment extends AbstractFillerFragment {
    public void collectAllData() {
        DataFiller allDataCollectedObject = dataExposer.exposeFiller();
        // by calling get...() you should have access to collected data.
    }
}
```

This only a sketch, but you'll get the picture. The idea is to keep a single object in your activity managed across activity restarts and to make it accessible through interfaces so you will respect the fragment to activity patterns.

Hope it makes sense ...

Comment: The problem is that like with onpause, onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstance) will not be called for all fragments, when I am viewing the last fragment.

Comment: You don't need to care about onpause. The data is available all the time everywhere whatever you do.

Comment: One thing to add: for each fragment you need to set edittext or other views to the data already in DataFiller. That could be done in onViewCreated.

Comment: I've edited my answer for `Page1Fragment` example to reflect just above comment. Hope it makes more sense ...

Answer (score 0):

2 solutions come to my mind.

The first one is to save user input data when your first 4 fragment's onpause() methods are called. You may save the data to a preference and then retrieve it from your 5th fragment.

The second approach is to persist your fragments while swiping.This way the swiping will be faster and cleaner and they want be recreated everytime a swipe happens:

```
yourcustomviewpager.setOffscreenPageLimit(5);
```

About setOffscreenPageLimit from [the android doc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html#setOffscreenPageLimit%28int%29):

> Set the number of pages that should be retained to either side of the current page in the view hierarchy in an idle state. Pages beyond this limit will be recreated from the adapter when needed.
>   This is offered as an optimization. If you know in advance the number of pages you will need to support or have lazy-loading mechanisms in place on your pages, tweaking this setting can have benefits in perceived smoothness of paging animations and interaction. If you have a small number of pages (3-4) that you can keep active all at once, less time will be spent in layout for newly created view subtrees as the user pages back and forth.
>   You should keep this limit low, especially if your pages have complex layouts. This setting defaults to 1.

Comment: The onpaused trick don't work because onpause is not called for page 3, when page 4(The last page) is viewed.

Comment: You are right. So you may save the input every time an input is changed(you should set listeners for your textviews).

Comment: Dam, that is a lot of code. And all I really need is a fragmentNotVisibleAnymore() method. I think I will try to use a setOnPageChangeListener which can then call a method in each fragment to collect all the data.

Comment: The second method is only one line of code and doesn't require to save data to a preference and also makes swiping smoother. Anyway it's your call. Do the way you think it's best:)

Comment: Almost true, but the second method require 4 more lines of code because it also require me to cache the objects I create in my Adapter, so I can get them again. But I guess that it is the best solution even thou it seems so wrong to do it this way. I will accept your answer if nothing better comes up, but it still feels wrong.

Comment: After more work I have concluded that the second solution is not really going to work, because when the user rotate the screen, the entire Activity is recreated which is going to mess up the "Keep the fragments, so I can reference them later"